# Twilio Target Worker Expression--blocking voice calls while on a text

Tags: twilio, expression, target, worker, twilio-taskrouter

I've read the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/multitasking#preventing-a-worker-from-receiving-chat-tasks-if-on-a-voice-task on how to block an agent from getting chats while they are on a voice call, but I want to do the reverse with a twist.

I successfully managed to stop workers from getting a voice call while they have an active chat going using "worker.channel.chat.assigned_tasks == 0" as the Expression. However, it also prevents a second chat, SMS, Facebook, or WhatsApp message coming in even though the worker's capacity is higher than 1.

Would love suggestions on what the expression should be so that the additional SMS or chats can come through up to the worker's capacity but not any voice calls when they have an active chat or SMS going.

Answer (score 1):

The following filter should do the trick. The expression will only apply to voice tasks and the target routes to workers with no assigned chats.

```
      {
        "filter_friendly_name": "Do not assign Voice Tasks if assigned Chat",
        "expression": "(task_channel_unique_name=='voice')",
        "targets": [
          {
            "queue": <default queue sid>,
            "expression": "worker.channel.chat.assigned_tasks == 0"
          }
        ]
      },
```